# How to edit/change code snippets automatically inserted by WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

There is this WebStorm beast, I like it, and it provides good services when I edit/develop my Angular.js application, but the code inserted automatically, protecting me to enter that code, is not fit for TSLint rules created also automatically by angular-client.

Example:

I created a new module (`AModule`) which should be included by another module (`module B`). When I enter `AMdule` in the import section of `BModule` then the intellisense offers me `AModule` and I hit enter and the module will be imported. But, it is imported this:

```
import {AModule} from "./services/AModule/AModule.module";
```

And I want this:

```
import { AModule } from './services/AModule/AModule.module';
```

I haven't found so far how can I make changes in these templates. How can I make changes like this? I searched for templates but they deal with something else in WebStorm.

Comment: You just need to change the Code Style settings for TypeScript, then it will generate code to match: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/code-style-typescript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Spaces`, enable `Within /
     ES6 import/export braces`
- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Punctuation`, set `Use` to *single*

Note that you can import code style prerefences from your tslint.json : open it in editor and click '*Yes*' when prompted to apply settings. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2455/, *Import code style from tslint.json*

Answer (score 3):

Check `Es6 import/exports braces"`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to look into
`setting` > search for `Live template` > find the snippet you want to edit

Comment: autoimports don't use live templates